# How to create a tomcat installer using inno setup?

Tags: tomcat, installation, inno-setup

Using Inno setup to create Apache tomcat installer windows, that could possibly deploy WAR or not, either way how do i create the installer, what files do i need to download and how do i customize the configuration files if needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note, that reposting the same question again, you doesn't change anything. You're looking for a complete solution, without posting any attempt that you've tried. Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a *write a code for me, please* service. If you'd show some effort or attempt to write a script by yourself and ask a specific question containing a description with what you're having problem, then we might help.

Comment: @Blash-Taz  Have you tried some thing related to this?             if yes, tell us what you did...                                    if no, you need to put some effort, that will help you later. Install Apache tomcat installer for windows(hope you have already did the installation)check the files locations, registry keys  and read inno setup help file.

Comment: @Blash- Taz just now,I have seen your previous question, The answer for your questions are in Inno setup help file only. Check this path **C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5** see Files section, Run Section,Code section and Exec function

Comment: oh ok, but the help file is not in that path i've checked...

Comment: sorry about the post it's my first time using this installer... i'm still trying to get the hang of it... trying to understand the script.

Comment: @Blash- Taz Inno help file : http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/

Comment: If you want whole turn key solution SO members will not help you. But if you are interested in Inno Setup services you can check this site: http://unsigned-softworks.sk/en/services.html (sorry for self promo).